# Using the data array from one array object as part of another array object

Tags: arrays, swift, mvvm, swiftui, model

I have two models, ExerciseModel and RoutineModel, in which a single routine is comprised of one or more exercises. I am trying to use the contents of the data array from the ExerciseArrayObject class as part of my RoutineArrayObject's data array.

I am receiving the following error:
`'self' used in property access 'exercises' before all stored properties are initialized`

Here is ExerciseArrayObject:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ExerciseArrayObject: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var dataArray = [ExerciseModel]()
    
    init() {
        
        //print("FETCH FROM DATABASE HERE")
        
        let exercise1 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userA", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 1", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "12 reps", setsInfo: "3 sets")
        let exercise2 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userB", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 2", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "8 reps", setsInfo: "4 sets")
        let exercise3 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userC", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 3", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "5 reps", setsInfo: "5 sets")
        let exercise4 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userD", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 4", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "20 reps", setsInfo: "10 sets")
        let exercise5 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userE", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 5", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "10 reps", setsInfo: "3 sets", sharedUserUsername: "Shared User")
        
        self.dataArray.append(exercise1)
        self.dataArray.append(exercise2)
        self.dataArray.append(exercise3)
        self.dataArray.append(exercise4)
        self.dataArray.append(exercise5)
    }
    
}
```

And here is RoutineArrayObject:

```swift
class RoutineArrayObject: ObservableObject {
    
    @ObservedObject var exercises: ExerciseArrayObject
    @Published var dataArray = [RoutineModel]()
    
    init() {
        
        //print("FETCH FROM DATABASE HERE")
        
        let routine1 = RoutineModel(routineID: "", userID: "", username: "user1", routineTitle: "Yoga Routine", exercises: exercises.dataArray, dateCreate: Date(), routineImage: "demoexercise", noOfExercises: "\(exercises.dataArray.count)")
        
        let routine2 = RoutineModel(routineID: "", userID: "", username: "user2", routineTitle: "Core Routine", exercises: exercises.dataArray, dateCreate: Date(), routineImage: "logo", noOfExercises: "\(exercises.dataArray.count)", sharedUserID: "", sharedUserUsername: "Shared User")
        
        self.dataArray.append(routine1)
        self.dataArray.append(routine2)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You could add the code in the init to a separate function and then call that function from your view in `.onAppear`

Comment: Or merge the two classes into one.

Comment: You should not have `@ObservedObject var exercises: ExerciseArrayObject` 
in `RoutineArrayObject`, `@ObservedObject` are used in Views, not classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ExerciseModel` and `RoutineModel` are structs,
you could try this approach using completion closures. This
keeps your two models and use the contents of the data array from
the `ExerciseArrayObject` class as part of your `RoutineArrayObject`'s data array.

```
class ExerciseArrayObject: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var dataArray = [ExerciseModel]()
    
    init() {
        ExerciseArrayObject.fetchExcersices() { arr in
            self.dataArray = arr
        }
    }
    
    static func fetchExcersices(completion: @escaping([ExerciseModel]) -> ()) {
        
        //print("FETCH FROM DATABASE HERE")
        var excersices = [ExerciseModel]()
        
        let exercise1 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userA", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 1", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "12 reps", setsInfo: "3 sets")
        let exercise2 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userB", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 2", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "8 reps", setsInfo: "4 sets")
        let exercise3 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userC", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 3", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "5 reps", setsInfo: "5 sets")
        let exercise4 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userD", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 4", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "20 reps", setsInfo: "10 sets")
        let exercise5 = ExerciseModel(exerciseID: "", userID: "", username: "userE", exerciseTitle: "Exercise 5", dateCreate: Date(), exerciseImage: "logo", repsInfo: "10 reps", setsInfo: "3 sets", sharedUserUsername: "Shared User")
        
        excersices.append(exercise1)
        excersices.append(exercise2)
        excersices.append(exercise3)
        excersices.append(exercise4)
        excersices.append(exercise5)
        
        completion(excersices)  // <-- todo deal with errors etc...
    }
    
}

class RoutineArrayObject: ObservableObject {

    @Published var dataArray = [RoutineModel]()
    
    init() {
        ExerciseArrayObject.fetchExcersices() { exercises in
            print("--> exerciseArray: \(exercises)")
            self.fetchRoutines(exercises: exercises) { _ in
                print("--> routineArray: \(self.dataArray)")
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchRoutines(exercises: [ExerciseModel], completion: @escaping(Bool) -> ()) {
        //print("FETCH FROM DATABASE HERE")
        
        let routine1 = RoutineModel(routineID: "", userID: "", username: "user1", routineTitle: "Yoga Routine", exercises: exercises, dateCreate: Date(), routineImage: "demoexercise", noOfExercises: exercises.count)
        
        let routine2 = RoutineModel(routineID: "", userID: "", username: "user2", routineTitle: "Core Routine", exercises: exercises, dateCreate: Date(), routineImage: "logo", noOfExercises: exercises.count, sharedUserID: "", sharedUserUsername: "Shared User")
        
        self.dataArray.append(routine1)
        self.dataArray.append(routine2)
        
        completion(true)  // <-- todo deal with errors etc...
    }
    
}
```

You can also use other techniques instead of basic completion closures, such as
async/await concurrency with tasks.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me and I understood most of what you were doing. I might have to go and learn what completion closures are in more detail though, as I was a bit confused there.

Comment: Note, my answer is just some quick code of an approach, there are many ways to achieve what you want.
If you are going to fetch data from a server, then definitely you should get a good understanding 
of closures.